# Refresh listview on receive of push notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification

How to reload a listview when you receive a push notifications on redux base react native application?

I have written logic for receiving push notifications on App.js file. Where as my listview is in Home.js

I am looking for a way to trigger a method name refreshList() from App.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are using redux the order should be quite clear:

1. Receive the data.
2. Dispatch an action with the data (maybe SET_PUSH_DATA).

Supposing that your component is connected to redux, and supposing I'm inside your listener:

```
this.props.yourActionName({ 
    type: "YOUR_ACTION_TYPE",
    payload: yourNewData
});
```

3. Update the list in your reducer.

in your reducer you should have an array to keep the data, so just add a case for this action:

```
case "YOUR_ACTION_TYPE":
    return {...state, yourListVariable: action.payload}
```

4. Get the list on mapStateToProps in your container component.

   const mapStateToProps = ({ YourListReducer }) => {
      return { list: YourListReducer.list };
   }

Once redux has updated its state you will get a new prop value in your container component and, consequently, this will trigger your component update cycle and a render will be triggered in your component with the new data, so you won't need a refreshList() on App.js because redux will handle the update for you.

Comment: sure, edit your question with the relevant details of your notification listener to start from there :)

Comment: well, there you go.